# Extend Azure 30 day trial

Tags: azure

I signed up for a 30 day Azure trial 3 days ago.  I have 2 vms.  Today, I have 2 messages popping up in my Management Portal.

*Your Free Trial expires in 25 day(s). Click here to upgrade now.*

*Based on your usage history ($21.52/day), you might use your remaining credit in about 3 days.*

*25 days left $67 credit remaining*

I feel like I cut the "speed-up countdown" wire on a time bomb in an 80's movie.

I'd like to fully evaluate Azure and I'm just getting started.  Clearly I missed something along the way that is preventing me from getting the full trial period.

Microsoft Support just gives me Azure's sales phone number.

Does someone know what I need to do to get a trial extension and stop the countdown from going too fast.

Thanks!

Comment: That's a really high spend rate for two VMs. Do they really need to be that big? I don't think you'd find too many companies that would allow you to 'trial' that kind of capacity free for 30 days.

Comment: If you stop the VM's from the management portal, those VM's will stop incurring charges.  It might be helpful if you explained what you're looking to get out of the trial, and what features of Azure you'd be using.

Comment: This got brought up on [this UserVoice issue](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/12241587-extend-the-30-day-trial-period-it-s-just-not-enou) as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a way to extend the trial period. If you have disable the spending limit, you account would operate without any problem, but yet, you would start incurring cost.

These are the ways you cut down costs

1. Reduce the size of isntance - say small ( A1 )
2. Recduce the instance count
3. At any point in time if you are not using your instance, you can stop the instance and you cost near ZERO cost during that time.
4. If you have MSDN Subscription or BizSpark Subscription would would get $150 everymonth as credits

Comment: Very helpful Naveen and Brendan Green.  Looks like I need to reduce the resources my vms use and stop them when I'm not using them.  Fair enough.

Comment: Anyone know why my post was down voted?  Did I break some kind of criteria for forming a question?

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that costs can be quickly used if you keep dropping and creating the database for testing purposes on azure, best to use existing database